# Trouble porting OpenGL app to Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opengl

I am trying to move an OpenGL app to Windows.

It was my understanding that Windows had a decent OpenGL implementation. But I'm starting to think that it doesn't...

Specifically, I use array buffers and [glDrawArrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318837(VS.85).aspx).

When I tried to compile my code in Visual Studio 2008 Pro, I received the following errors:

```
vertexbuffers.cpp(31) : error C3861: 'glGenBuffers': identifier not found
vertexbuffers.cpp(32) : error C2065: 'GL_ARRAY_BUFFER' : undeclared identifier
vertexbuffers.cpp(32) : error C3861: 'glBindBuffer': identifier not found
vertexbuffers.cpp(33) : error C2065: 'GL_ARRAY_BUFFER' : undeclared identifier
vertexbuffers.cpp(33) : error C2065: 'GL_STATIC_DRAW' : undeclared identifier
vertexbuffers.cpp(33) : error C3861: 'glBufferData': identifier not found
```

When I examined `<GL\gl.h>` (contained in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include\gl`), I saw:

```
/* ClientArrayType */ 
/*      GL_VERTEX_ARRAY */
/*      GL_NORMAL_ARRAY */
/*      GL_COLOR_ARRAY */
```

**Update** but it would seem that those contants get defined elsewhere.

How am I supposed to generate buffers if I don't have access to those functions?

The documentation doesn't say that those array types are disabled. How do I get access to the **real** implementation on OpenGL on Windows?

Comment: Could you past the specific errors? It is possible that those comments are for documentation and that things are properly defined elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I jumped the gun with those functions. My real errors come from the Buffer generation functions. Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for posting those, it helped me understand and fix up my answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The #defines are commented out in the header file whenever they would otherwise be repeated. Look at line 1054 of gl.h:

```
/* vertex_array */
#define GL_VERTEX_ARRAY                   0x8074
```

If this #define is actually missing then you should probably replace the file with a fresh copy.

If you look at [the documentation for glGenBuffers](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenBuffers.xml) you will see that it is only available in OpenGL 1.5 and higher. The header file for Windows only comes with OpenGL 1.2 and you should use the extension mechanism to access the newer functionality. If you call [wglGetProcAddress](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenBuffers.xml) with the function name, e.g.

```
void (__stdcall *glGenBuffers)(GLsizei,GLuint*) =
    wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
```

then you have a pointer to the function.

Comment: You have better eyes than me. Thank you for the reference. Unfortunately, I still have errors revolving around glBindBuffer.

Comment: edited after i looked at the errors you were recieving. unfortunately the header is 1.2 only, but there are easy fixes. :)

Answer (score 8):

You might give GLEW a shot:

http://glew.sourceforge.net/

I'm pretty sure I used it at some time in the past, and makes this sort of thing a little easier and more portable.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that the buffer functions are only available on Windows as extension methods.

OpenGL provides [glext.h](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/glext.h) that declares pointers to all of these functions. It is then up to my app to use [wglGetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374386(VS.85).aspx) to get pointers to the functions.

For example:

```
PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC myglBindBuffers = 
    (PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffersARB");
```

Thankfully, I only have to do it for about 4 functions. Unfortunately, I now have to add platform-dependent code to my app.

Comment: +1 for the sensible way to find these type definitions - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's support for OpenGL stretches only as far as OpenGL-1.1 up to Windows XP, and OpenGL-1.4 starting with Vista. Any OpenGL functionality beyond those must be delivered and supported by the installable client driver (ICD), i.e. the GPU driver's OpenGL implmenentation. To access the advanced functionality, OpenGL provides the so called *Extension System*, formed by *wglGetProcAddress*, which is kind of like *GetProcAddress* for DLLs, but gives access to functions of the OpenGL implementation (=driver).

To make things easier, nice wrapper libraries like GLEW have been developed, which do all the grunt work initializing all the available OpenGL extensions, providing them to the end user.